# EF Core Add-Migration Issue - How to fix out of sync migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I have a .Net Core 2.2 MVC App running locally, with added scaffolded Identity as the authentication (I have all the ASPNetUsers/ASPNetRoles tables etc). I am using a Postgres Database. I also have two 2 context class in my project, one is the `IdentityDbContext` which was added with the scaffolded Identity code and i have my `DbContext` which maps all my non Identity tables in my project.

Here is my `IdentityDbContext` class:

```
public class PhotoUploaderFormContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public PhotoUploaderFormContext(DbContextOptions<PhotoUploaderFormContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

This simply maps my `ApplicationUser.cs` class (which is the user account for logging into my App). Everything was working fine prior with regards to adding new properties to my `ApplicationUser.cs` class, Adding a Migration, Updating Database, and then these additional properties appear in my `ASPNetUsers` table.

I have recently tried to add another property to my `Application.cs` class. (It has been a long while since I have done, and there as been additional migrations added with my `DbContext` class in between).

The migration code looked correct:

```
  public partial class templateSubmission : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "SubmitTemplateFormAccess",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                nullable: true);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "SubmitTemplateFormAccess",
                table: "AspNetUsers");
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to `Update-Database` , (using the `IdentityDbContext`), I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079 initialized 'PhotoUploaderFormContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' with options: None
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (37ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid=c.relnamespace WHERE c.relname='__EFMigrationsHistory');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (83ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid=c.relnamespace WHERE c.relname='__EFMigrationsHistory');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (128ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT "MigrationId", "ProductVersion"
      FROM "__EFMigrationsHistory"
      ORDER BY "MigrationId";
Applying migration '20200217104808_CreateIdentitySchema'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
      Applying migration '20200217104808_CreateIdentitySchema'.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (240ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
          "Id" text NOT NULL,
          "Name" character varying(256) NULL,
          "NormalizedName" character varying(256) NULL,
          "ConcurrencyStamp" text NULL,
          CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
      );
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 1032
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 490
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 332
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1218
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1042
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1025
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
Failed executing DbCommand (240ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
    "Id" text NOT NULL,
    "Name" character varying(256) NULL,
    "NormalizedName" character varying(256) NULL,
    "ConcurrencyStamp" text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 1032
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 490
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 332
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1218
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1042
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 1025
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
42P07: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists
```

It seems to be applying an older migration - `20200217104808_CreateIdentitySchema` . This was the initial migration that created all of my Identity tables, such as `ASPNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins` etc.

Any idea how to fix this mess? I have been trying for several days but unable to. Online suggestions where to delete all my migrations and start over, but I wanted to see if i could avoid that. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have one stable migration version in migrationHistory table,
then

```
1: run update-database {MIGRATION_NAME_WITHOUT DATE}
2: run remove-migration
3: run add-migrarion (this will add migrations for any pending changes)
4: finally run "update-database"
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Do you mean try to run the latest migration from my EF_MigrationsHistory table?

Comment: Yes the latest on from EF_MigrationsHistory table, on which database was already in stable state

Comment: The trouble is, whats in my EF_MigrationsHistory table, are the migrations that I have added that use `DbContext`. My migrations that I added using `IdentityDbContext` do not appear in this table.